# Custom telerik gridview for winforms doesn't bind the data

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

Custom control for telerik grid view in winforms

> In my Windows forms control library:

for MyGrid.cs (where MyGrid.cs is a component class)

public MyGrid : `Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView`

I build and i have MyGrid.dll & i have added that in my visual studio toolbox (also referenced that dll in my consuming winform app).

Consuming winform app:

1. In Form1.cs, i drag and drop that MyGrid  & i write this code:

> ```
> MyGrid1.DataSource=ds.Table[0]; //Dataset
> ```

The grid doesn't get bound with records, whereas when i check ds `row count it has 150 records`. The grid however shows me green and white color (ie. alternating row color), but doesn't bind the data.

This is the code that consuming winform uses

```
    DataSet ds  = null;
    string connectionString = "Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=DBname;Integrated Security=True";
    string sql = " SELECT ID,FirstName from table1 ";
    SqlConnection connection = null;            


     connnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
     ds= new System.Data.DataSet();
     connection.Open();
     dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Table1");

     MyGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

where MyGrid1 is the custom control that is being dragged and dropped from toolbox.

Custom control code:

```
        this.EnableAlternatingRowColor = true;
        this.TableElement.AlternatingRowColor  = System.Drawing.Color.Green;            
        this.MasterTemplate.AutoSizeColumnsMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

The telerik grid is not binding the data, however when i click on the cell, it shows me the value. Any thoughts?